# Sorting by Column Header Click Removes Column Filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, filter, columnheader

I have a gridview table that has auto generated columns and the rows in those columns can be sorted by clicking the column name since I have "AllowSorting" on. I also have checkbox lists that the user can check or uncheck to filter columns in and out of the table.

The problem is when the user filters the table to whatever columns they want and then they click on any column name, it will sort by that column but it brings back all of the columns that they filtered out.

I am guessing that I might need to create a method with GridViewSortEventArgs or DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs but when I have `protected void method(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)` it gives me the error "The type or namespace name could not be found but `GridViewSortEventArgs` will not return an error like that. I'm basically thinking I should try to make it when you click on the column headers to do almost the same exact thing as when you click the search button after you select what columns you want in the table so it will run the query with the filtered columns instead of basically selecting * columns and then sorting.

How do I go about this?